# Invalid update error when updating Core Data relationship in SwiftUI if it results in reordering of list sections in UI

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui, nested-lists

## Context

I am using Core Data in a SwiftUI app. I have a `Box` entity, which has a to-many relationship to an `Item` entity. I fetch the data using `@FetchRequest` and use a `struct` like below to sort, filter and group the data. This uses a `SortOrder` enum for options like sorting by `name`, `creationDate` and other properties.

```
struct ItemSorter {
    static public func sortedItems(items: FetchedResults<Item>, sortOrder: Item.SortOrder, ascending: Bool = true, grouped: Bool = true, filterText: String = "") -> [ItemSection] {
    }
}
```

The `ItemSection` is a struct that has an `items` property which is an array of the items in that section.

Each `Box` has a `boxItems` property that returns all the items in that box.

The `BoxSorter` implementation is simpler and just returns an array of boxes. These are displayed in a `ForEach` within a `List`. Nested inside this, each section uses a `ForEach` to display each of its items. The user can select to order the boxes by the number of items contained within.

```
struct BoxSorter {
    static public func sortedBoxes(boxes: FetchedResults<Box>, sortOrder: Box.SortOrder, ascending: Bool = true) -> [Box] {
    }
}
```

A context menu on each item allows the user to move it to a different box.

```
.contextMenu {
    Menu {
        ForEach(boxes.wrappedValue.filter { $0 != box } ) { box in
            Button {
                item.box = box
                dataController.save()
            } label: {
                Label("\(box.boxName)", image: box.boxIcon)
            }
        }
    } label: {
        Label("Move Item", systemImage: "chevron.right")
    }
}
```

## The Problem

The app crashes with an `Invalid update` error (stating there is a mismatch in the number of rows before an after updates), if the user moves an item to another box AND if doing this causes the boxes themselves to be reordered (e.g. if the user has selected to order them by the number of items in each one).

Other updates work fine. Even moving an item between boxes is fine if it does not cause the boxes to be reordered in the UI.

## Attempted solutions

Running the `item.box = box` line in various dispatch queues or with delays does not help. Commenting out the `dataController.save()` line does not help.

Preventing the use of animation does not help.

Strangely, changing the ID used for each box in the `ForEach` to use `id: \.boxIdentifier` seems to prevent the issue, but `\.self` still causes the crash. However, doing this causes weird animation artefacts in the list!

## Is this a bug?

Is there a way to fix this, or could it be a SwiftUI / Core Data bug?

I am not sure if my usage of a sorting and filtering struct is the best way, but it seems to work well elsewhere in the app.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried do this with a simple `Menu`? It could be that `Menu` just doesnt work well with the changes. `TabView` does the same thing when you try to delete or add items.

Comment: So, does this line cause the crash? "drug.box = box"

Comment: @loremipsum Thanks I'll give that a try. You mean use this as a menu from a button rather than a context menu on a view?

Comment: @SardorbekRuzmatov Sorry that's a typo from when I was making my code examples generic. It should read `item.box = box` - I have changed it in the code. It is simply changing the item from one box to another. The crash just occurs at the `@main` app struct and I cannot find a specific problematic line in the trace.

Comment: Just a menu that doesn't do anything. Try it with a simple array of strings and try to add and delete or moving the items. Take CoreData out of the equation basically and see if it is even possible. `Menu` might not be dynamic it may not accept changes dynamically.